# Javascript Nested Loop Matching, Combining, Replacing

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested-loops

I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
arr2 = ["z", "q", "a", "v", "y", "e"]
```

I want to produce a an array of results to be this:

```
results = ["aa", "b", "c", "d", "ee", "f", "g"]
```

Basically I want to push into a results array everything in order in arr1 and if it has a match combine with the matching key, if not still list the item from arr1. So the results array is every item in arr1 but if it matched anywhere in obj 2 take the matching key and combine it. Note: results[0] is arr1[0] + arr2[2] not arr1[0] + arr1[0]

My actual problem is more complex, but I think this is the best simplification I can deduce. I am looking for a nested loop (or any way that works) that would produce this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I know I'm close but so far I have not been able to produce this, and have been pulling my hair out trying. Thank you!

Comment: *I know I'm close but sor far I have not been able to produce this* . Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Pedantry, but if `arr1[0]` and `arr2[2]` are the same it really doesn't matter what you add together for the result.

Comment: `var results = arr1.map( function(val) { return val + (arr2.indexOf(val) > -1 ? val : ''); } );`

Comment: (As Juhana's answer shows... but it's not clear what should happen if `arr2` contains multiple `"a"`s, or even if that's possible.)

Comment: I didn't post that as an answer because I have a feeling the actual problem is not that simple.

Comment: @Dave - good question, arr2 will not contain multiple "a"s. For your first question, they need to be combined because the actual problem is dealing with giant nested objects, and the actual combined results are not identical, that is "a" is just one key in an object. hope that makes sense

Comment: If you want a solution that applies to  your actual problem,  you should show your actual code. Or at least an example that matches the actual data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Juhana Here is my actual code, if you can take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/esgeLayj/  I thought it would be too hard to explain on here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by [Juhana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana):

```
var results = arr1.map(function (val) { 
  return val + (arr2.indexOf(val) > -1 ? val : ''); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the map method, I think that's what I need, will reply soon if I can get it to work